# Tensorflow and conditional accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics

I use a standard way to compute accuracy:

```
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

However, most of the labels are 0 ( i.e. Y=[1,0,0,..] ). I would like to restrict the computation of the accuracy on the labels. I tried the following:

```
correct_pred = tf.equal( tf.argmax( prediction[tf.where(Y[0]!=1)], 1) , 
                         tf.argmax(Y[tf.where(Y[0]!=1)], 1) )
```

This does not work as it changes the tensors size:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 3 for 'strided_slice_2' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [?,3], [1,?,0], [1,?,0], [1].

What is the correct way to do this kind of things?